# Inserting data to mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

In my php program, I have to insert variables into one of my sql tables. Every time I go to test this out though, the values don't get posted to the table. Is there something wrong with these statements? or is the problem bigger than these 2 lines

```
$sqli = mySQLi_connect("localhost","root","root","myProject");

mysqli_query("insert into purchases (id, productID, quantity) values ($id, $productID, $quantity)");
```

Comment: don't insert id it should be auto incremented. variables should be in single quotes too. like this values ('$productID','$quantity')

Comment: There's no way to tell without knowing what value `$id` etc. have and where they come from

Comment: they are posted from a form in the previous page

Comment: Sometimes records do get inserted and people make a mistake when looking.  It's best to check this sort of thing directly against the database, ie. don't rely on your php code for that.

Comment: `or die(mysqli_error());` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try it by using

```
mysqli_query("insert into purchases (id, productID, quantity) values ('$id', '$productID', '$quantity')");
```

you are missing a single quotes in those variables

Comment: This wouldn't work because you're missing the connector in the procedural style code

Answer (score 0):

If you use mysqli_query in a procedural way, you need to use the connection as your first parameter like this

```
mysqli_query($sqli, "insert into purchases (id, productID, quantity) 
    values ($id, $productID, $quantity)");
```

Otherwise you can use it in an OOP manner like this:

```
$sqli->query("insert into purchases (id, productID, quantity) 
    values ($id, $productID, $quantity)");
```

If you turned on error reporting on your code, you should have figured out the problem as the following warning is produced:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/jkiang/test.php on line 10
```

Comment: Note that I did not put single quotes here just because I copied from OP assuming that they are of INT type in mysql and that he would be doing validation or intval() on the values before putting them in the query.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are mixing your procedural and your object oriented mysqli. Second, you have no error checking. Without knowing what your variables contain I suggest you try something like this:

```
$sqli = new mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","myProject");

if($sqli->connect_errno > 0){
    die("Connection couldn't be established");
}

$q = "insert into purchases (id, productID, quantity) values ($id, $productID, $quantity)";

if(!$result = $sqli->query($q)){
    die("There was an error with your query");
}

$sqli->close();
```